# I cant update my object value , for my Java script game (canvas)

Tags: javascript, object, canvas

This is my Constructor for game enemy:

```
enter code here:

/// my constructor for enemy
function masinaCon(x,y,width,height,color){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;
    this.color=color;
    this.draw=function(){
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
    };

}
// color of contsructor
function color(){
    return 'rgb('+Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*180)+')';
}

// array of enemy
var niz=[];
```

///////////////////////////// end of code

i filled the array(var niz=[]) with 10 objects and i  wanted to move the third object 2pixels down, so that repeats in every frame, in order for it to look like a game(falling effect => niz[2].y+=2;)

And when i print, the cordinates in the object are increasing but, when i print them(the objects), there is no change(visually), could someone help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

It simple. The x and y references the original ones from the constructor. Just update the x and y inside the draw function to reference the object ones using `this`

```
this.draw=function(){
    ctx.fillStyle=color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height); // x->this.x etc
};
```